# How to implement Google Pay in Server Side in C# (dot net web api) using Stripe Payment Gateway?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, stripe-payments, google-pay

I want to implement the google pay in my server side code but no code or method available in stripe payment gateway. My payment type is google pay, not card type. I also see stripe document https://stripe.com/docs/google-pay but I did't find any server code. I find only install dependency in server code but don't find implementation method in server side in google pay.

I want to implement the google pay code in server side dot net c# web api.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's more of frontend than backend for enabling Google Pay in your website.

You just need to create a PaymentIntent with `payment_method_types=['card']` in the backend and pass the `clientSecret` to the frontend.

Read this [doc](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button) for the complete integration guide.